# Display link on top of image and lower image opacity when mouseover of centre of image only?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to only lower opacity and display link when I hover over the centre of my image? Have gone through trial and error, adding width, height, margins all over with no success. Currently the code works fine when I mouse over the image. But I would like it to only change opacity and display the link on mouseover of the centre of the image, something like an area of 500px width x 325px height.

```
<div class="processor-container">
            <div class="processor-image-container">
                <img class="processor-image" src="images/shop/cpu.png" alt="">
                <div class="processor-link-container">
                    <a class="processor-link" href="shopprocessors.html">Shop Processors</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.processor-container {
  padding: 100px 0 100px 0;
}

.processor-image-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.processor-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.processor-image, .processor-link-container {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.processor-link-container {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.processor-link {

  display: block;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline #f76441;
}


.processor-image-container:hover .processor-link-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

.processor-image-container:hover .processor-image {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the `onmouseover` Javascript event, which provides the properties `offsetX` and `offsetY`.